# pass selected return from a function to another

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to pass a value from a function to other.

I compute the values of funcA which returns two values a, b. These are numpy array.

After that computation is done, I wanted to pass the only value, **for example, *a* from funcA to funcB** and do other computations there. I want to ignore "b" from funA while passing "a". I am intrigued if that is possible?

```
def funA(self, x, y):
 .......
return a, b


def funcB(self, data):
......**use only a from funA**.....
return c
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could simply ignore the second value returned by `funA`:

```
def funA(x, y):
  print('Calling %s with %r, %r' % ('funA', x, y))
  return x, y

def funB(a):
  print('Calling %s with %r' % ('funB', a))
  return a

x, _ = funA(1, 2)
funB(x)
# Calling funA with 1, 2
# Calling funB with 1
```

Another alternative is to use the first element of the tuple returned by `funA`:

```
funB(funA(1, 2)[0])
# Calling funA with 1, 2
# Calling funB with 1
```